# How to generate a uniform size circle bitmap from different size image

Tags: android, image-processing, canvas, bitmap

Currently I'm using this code..

```
            public static Bitmap getCircularBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int borderWidth) {
            if (bitmap == null || bitmap.isRecycled()) {
                return null;
            }

            int width = bitmap.getWidth() + borderWidth;
            int height = bitmap.getHeight() + borderWidth;

            Bitmap canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, TileMode.CLAMP,  TileMode.CLAMP);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setShader(shader);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
            float radius = width > height ? ((float) height) / 2f: ((float) width) / 2f;
            canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius, paint);
            paint.setShader(null);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth);
            canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius - borderWidth / 2,  paint);
            return canvasBitmap;
        }
```

Its returns a circular bitmap, but size of images getting different according to real image size.

A sample Image of app..

[image]

first profile image is smaller then second.

Please help me out..
Thanks.

Comment: Keep a fixed size for `radius`

Comment: change your code in last draw Circle 
radius - borderWidth / 2 to radius + borderWidth / 2.

Comment: @Divyang Metalia Its not working.

Comment: @Apoorv I tried to fix the radius, but that's also not working.

Comment: @Ankit can you post an image what it look like and would you like it to be

Comment: @Ankit if you want same size then reduce your bitmap.Means change bitmap width remove radius from width and height.

Comment: @ Divyang Metalia can you tell me how would i do that.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin you can the image now.